# How to enable history picklist while typing

Tags: powershell, autocomplete, powershell-7.3, psreadline

I'm trying to become one with PowerShell and found a feature that I really love but do not understand how to make it work consistently.

PowerShell can go into a mode where it shows an incrementally updated picklist of history items as you type.  You can then up and down arrow through them to select the one you want to run and hit enter.

By default my PowerShell configuration just shows the last matching command on the command line as you type and if it is what you want to run you can hit right arrow then enter.  I want the default to be the picklist.   How do I enable this feature?

Here is a picture of the picklist I awant in action.  Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To switch from the default *inline* predictions (`InlineView`) to *list-based* predictions, put the following in your `$PROFILE` file:

```bash
Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionViewStyle ListView
```

To toggle between inline and list view *in-session* (non-persistently), use <kbd>F2</kbd>.

See also:

- [Using predictors in PSReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-predictors)
- The [`Set-PSReadLineOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PSReadline/Set-PSReadlineOption) help.